# timepicker selected value text size

Tags: android, android-studio, datetimepicker, timepicker

I want to change the selected text value size of a time picker.

**Do we have any libraries for the same?**

As I searched we do not have any customization in android. Need to develop a **UI similar to iOS time picker**.

Answer (score 0):

For android [brucetoo/PickView](https://github.com/brucetoo/PickView) similar to IOS,

This is a helper lib for us to pick date or province like IOS system WheelView widget.

Added feature to pick time with WheelView Widget

**Dependencies**

```
   compile 'com.brucetoo.pickview:library:1.2.3'
```

---

**to use**

```
 DatePickerPopWin pickerPopWin = new DatePickerPopWin.Builder(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerPopWin.OnDatePickedListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDatePickCompleted(int year, int month, int day, String dateDesc) {
                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dateDesc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                    }).textConfirm("CONFIRM") //text of confirm button
                           .textCancel("CANCEL") //text of cancel button
                           .btnTextSize(16) // button text size
                           .viewTextSize(25) // pick view text size
                           .colorCancel(Color.parseColor("#999999")) //color of cancel button
                           .colorConfirm(Color.parseColor("#009900"))//color of confirm button
                           .minYear(1990) //min year in loop
                           .maxYear(2550) // max year in loop
                           .showDayMonthYear(true) // shows like dd mm yyyy (default is false) 
                           .dateChose("2013-11-11") // date chose when init popwindow
                           .build();
```

[image]

Comment: @Sahana Prabhakar isnt your issue solved by this answer ? as per your question i have given you library on git that will solve your issue.

Comment: This library is outdated. dont use it