# Codename One - Picker on Android like on iOS

Tags: android, codenameone, picker

I like the native iOS Picker. I don't like the native Android Picker. Can I have on Android the same style and the same behavior of the iOS Picker?

Comment: If someone hasn't already created it, you can create a custom view yourself by extending the view. You can read more about creating custom views here: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307761/2826147)

Comment: Are your comments pertinent to Codename One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's implemented natively due to the circular effect on iOS that's a bit hard to replicate in the drawing primitives. We are thinking about moving this to lightweight code which will allow that but it would take a lot of work.

Personally I prefer the native Android pickers for some tasks see https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html

I think the separate Time and Date pickers are superior on Android.